# Identificar se scroll do mouse está rolando pra cima ou pra baixo

Tags: javascript

É possível com Javascript saber se o scroll do mouse está rolando pra cima ou pra baixo?

Comment: Tenho uma resposta que tem isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o código abaixo possa ajudar:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {

    // mesma posição
    if (e.scrollY === lastScrollTop) return;

    console.log(this.scrollY < lastScrollTop ? "Cima" :  "Baixo")

    lastScrollTop = this.scrollY;

  }, true)
```

Basicamente, eu sempre salvo a última posição do scroll atual. Quando o valor anterior é menor que o valor atual de `scrollY`, significa que estou rolando pra cima, caso contrário, para baixo.

`this.scrollY` sempre retorna a posição atual `scroll` de `window`, começando de `0`, quando estiver no topo da página.

Answer (score 1):

É sim possível fazer isto em javascript, com o script abaixo você consegue identificar no `console.log`:

```
<script>

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

if (body.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    body.addEventListener("mousewheel", detectarDirecaoRolagem, false);
    // Firefox
    body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", detectarDirecaoRolagem, false);
}

function detectarDirecaoRolagem( e )
{
    var delta = null,
        direction = false
    ;
    if ( !e ) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    if ( e.wheelDelta ) { // funciona na maioria dos casos
        delta = e.wheelDelta / 60;
    } else if ( e.detail ) { // funciona no Firefox
        delta = -e.detail / 2;
    }
    if ( delta !== null ) {
        direction = delta > 0 ? 'cima' : 'baixo';
    }

    console.log(direction);

    return direction;
}
</script>
```